# svg+xml file format: what determines dpi?

Tags: xml, svg, dpi

I have created a new document from scratch with InkSkape (Ubuntu). I have chosen "A0" as the page size (all predefined page sizes are shown in mm, regardless of what unit you choose as "default units"; however if you define a custom page size you can choose the units).

I have saved it both as "Inkscape SVG" and "plain SVG" which are both XML.

In both cases, the resulting XML file (of the empty document) only defines a width and height for the document in PIXELS (namely 4212.9922 by 2979.9211), and there's no mention whatsoever of either a DPI density or a document size in millimeters or inches or any other "real life" unit.

So, where is it that it is defined that 841mm equals 2979.9211 pixels? 
That yelds 90 dpi, but it is not mentioned anywhere in the XML (as far as I can decypher). Is that density fixed by the svg standard or is it perhaps the default density according to the standard (and a different one could be set), or is it an arbitrary assumption of the Inkscape program (in which case any other software reading the file may assume any other different density)?

Here's the "plain SVG":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="4212.9922"
   height="2979.9211"
   id="svg2">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
     rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type
       rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
    <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="translate(0,1927.5591)"
     id="layer1" />
</svg>
```

And here is the "inkscape SVG":

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="4212.9922"
   height="2979.9211"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
   sodipodi:docname="empty.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="489.28571"
     inkscape:cy="2462.8571"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1072"
     inkscape:window-height="663"
     inkscape:window-x="211"
     inkscape:window-y="27"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     units="mm" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
     rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type
       rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
    <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,1927.5591)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [developer question](https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/54978) they picked that maybe because they tought it said so in the SVG specification but that's not right as the SVG specification says use CSS 2.1 and that says it's [96 DPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html) (72 / 0.75)

If the Inkscape developers don't know or can't remember then I guess it just is what it is :-)

Comment: And it can't be changed in a document?

Comment: Inkscape [0.92](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.92#Important_changes): The default resolution was changed from 90dpi to 96dpi, to match the CSS standard.